# react native - ios - enabling Larger Text form accessibility messed up everything

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

So far my app was looking gorgeous but as soon as this "Larger Text" option is enabled from "Accessibility" everything started looking dirty, even the navigation bar.

Please suggest a way to handle these changes intelligently.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of source code digging & Google searching, it seems you can use the `AccessibilityManager` native module. I don't see any documentation for it but an example function can be seen in [this test file](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/26684cf3adf4094eb6c405d345a75bf8c7c0bf88/IntegrationTests/AccessibilityManagerTest.js):

```
AccessibilityManager.setAccessibilityContentSizeMultipliers({
  'extraSmall': 1.0,
  'small': 2.0,
  'medium': 3.0,
  'large': 4.0,
  'extraLarge': 5.0,
  'extraExtraLarge': 6.0,
  'extraExtraExtraLarge': 7.0,
  'accessibilityMedium': 8.0,
  'accessibilityLarge': 9.0,
  'accessibilityExtraLarge': 10.0,
  'accessibilityExtraExtraLarge': 11.0,
  'accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge': 12.0,
});
```

For reference, this seems to be the default values:

```
{UIContentSizeCategoryExtraSmall: @0.823,
 UIContentSizeCategorySmall: @0.882,
 UIContentSizeCategoryMedium: @0.941,
 UIContentSizeCategoryLarge: @1.0,
 UIContentSizeCategoryExtraLarge: @1.118,
 UIContentSizeCategoryExtraExtraLarge: @1.235,
 UIContentSizeCategoryExtraExtraExtraLarge: @1.353,
 UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityMedium: @1.786,
 UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityLarge: @2.143,
 UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityExtraLarge: @2.643,
 UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityExtraExtraLarge: @3.143,
 UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: @3.571}
```

Comment: This was by far the easiest solution, thanks for answering!

Answer (score 3):

You need to disable font scaling in your app for this to not happen. To do this, put this line in class constructor found in `index.ios.js`

```
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
```

Note: This may shrink your font, depending on what your *accessibility settings* were previously, but now you are free to set `fontSize` to whatever you want.

Comment: I have done that and it does fix the problem, but what I need is something more intelligent, I mean if user had it enabled there must be a reason for that and app should be able to adopt towards those preferences.

Comment: Why do you require something more intelligent? This is the standard implementation